# Sending data from custom inputs in Wordpress comment form in the admin notification email

Tags: php, hooks, comments

I have added a number custom inputs to the standard Wordpress comment form. Currently, I don't send these values to the database, but I know I can send this data to commentmeta table if I need to.

I am wanting to use the hook "comment_moderation_text" to add the data from the custom inputs to the admin notification email that gets sent when a comment is submitted.

Is there a way to do this/what is the best way to do this?